# Trouble setting up debugger for love2d in VS Code

Tags: lua, vscode-debugger, love2d

Found two debuggers for Lua, Local Lua Debugger(LLD) and Lua Debug.
But couldn't set up properly.  LLD keeps saying "no code to run" and Lua Debug can't find module.  Pictures provided below.

[LLD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKOAU.png)
[Lua Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l99sJ.png)

[Launch Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOM8f.png)